# Manage Standard Input/Output in another Thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, inputstream, outputstream

The basic rundown is...

1) My application starts a Java process and manages it.

2) I have a TCP Server in another thread that users can connect to and issue commands that the Java process understands.

3) Passing the commands is not a problem is streamWriter.WriteLine(cmd); but getting the response is proving to be difficult.

The next line that comes in through RedirectStandardError (it uses this instead of Output for some reason) should be the reply, but I am having trouble figuring out how to access that in my TCP Server's thread.

This is what my TCP Server's function looks like that needs to get the reply and print it out. How can I go about doing this?

```
    static void AcceptClient(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        TcpListener rconListener = ar.AsyncState as TcpListener;
        TcpClient rconClient = rconListener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("New client: " + rconClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

        NetworkStream ns = rconClient.GetStream();

        // Loop while client is Connected
        while (rconClient.Connected)
        {
            byte[] buff = new byte[4096];
            List<byte> msg = new List<byte>();
            int total = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                int read = ns.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                if (read <= 0)
                    break;

                msg.AddRange(buff);
                total += read;

                if (read < buff.Length)
                    break;
            }
            if (msg.Count <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Lost connection: " + rconClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                rconClient.Close();
                break;
            }

            int len = BitConverter.ToInt32(msg.ToArray(), 0);
            int seq = BitConverter.ToInt32(msg.ToArray(), 4);

            PacketType packetType = (PacketType)BitConverter.ToInt32(msg.ToArray(), 8);
            List<byte> response = new List<byte>();


            // RCON Execute Command
            if (packetType == PacketType.ServerData_ExecCommand_AuthResponse)
            {
                string srvcmd = ReadString(msg.ToArray(), 12);
                Console.WriteLine("RCON: " + srvcmd);

                response.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)seq));
                response.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)PacketType.ServerData_ResponseValue));

                string[] cmdargs = srvcmd.Split(new char[] { ' ' });

                if (cmdargs[0] == "rcon_password")
                {
                    ServerSettings.RCONPassword = cmdargs[1];
                    response.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("RCON Password succesfully changed to " + cmdargs[1]));
                }
                else if (cmdargs[0] == "date")
                {
                    response.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToString()));
                }
                else
                {
                    Program.SendRCONCmd(cmdargs[0]);
                }


                response.AddRange(new byte[] { 0x20, 0x0a }); //LF
                response.Add(0x0);
                response.Add(0x0);
                response.InsertRange(0, BitConverter.GetBytes((response.Count)));
                ns.Write(response.ToArray(), 0, response.Count);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you checked the SDK documentation?

**Process.StandardError Property**

[Gets a stream used to read the error output of the application.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I have no problem with that. As I mentioned, the issue is that I am not sure of how I should pass it to my TCP Server's thread to display to that user.

Comment: so are you able to receive the response from the server or not?

Comment: I receive the reply from the sub-process (Java app) fine, but I can't find a good way to pass it over to my TCP Server to send to the client, since my server is in another thread.

Comment: Assuming you are using .NET 4, I would investigate using the task parallel library - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx.  There are lots of nice hooks for passing data between threads